# Splitting string into tokens ignoring substrings wrapped in ""

Tags: c, string, substring, strtok

I am creating my own command line parser and I am splitting substrings with `strok()` and delimiters of `\t` (whitespaces)

However, if the substring is wrapped in `\"` it makes sense that its contents should not be split, because substrings need to freely contain whitespace characters.

Is there any known function or easy method to do that?

Comment: There's no standard library function to do that. You could look at the Posix `wordexp` function (if it exists on your platform) but be very careful when you use it because it can execute arbitrary shell commands (using the `WRDE_NOCMD` flag helps), and has undefined (and possibly insecure) behaviour if special character like `<` are in the string. Read the docs carefully.

Comment: I've really progressed on the command-line parser (which actually is more like a real time interpreter-scripting tool for my program) and I am tired and I would rather not use this function, because while it MAY exist on my platform (Windows but cygwin), it is a very slow function, probably not optimized at all and I am a bit lazy to attempt to learn how to use this function as it looks fairly complicated.

Comment: I wasn't really recommending its use, tbh, which is why I didn't make it an answer. If I were to answer, I'd stick with "there is no useful standard function, but it's not a bad introductory exercise for learning flex". :-) Still, it *might* have been useful to know about. (On Windows, there is actually a slightly more useful function. The windows shell doesn't word split command lines, so you need to use a library function to do it. EDIT: `CommandLineToArgvW`.)

Comment: @rici Just saw this function, good catch. Could be in fact useful especially for applications that are intended to be running under Windows.
Since I use cygwin and not for instance MSV I am targeting to not windowsize my application too much to make the porting easy.
That being said maybe I can get the `strtok` implementation and modify its behavior, maybe this is _close to_ an easy solution

Comment: It's easy to parse the quotes. The problem is correct handling of backslashes, particularly on windows where people often use backslashes as directory separators. But it's not *too* complicated. I'd use a state machine rather than strtok, because actually strtok is not very fast and not very flexible. Good luck.

Comment: This question is not useful to anyone. It shows no effort, it is unclear, it is a complete toxic impurity. It deserves more downovotes, because it doesn't help anybody and also can never.

Answer (score 0):

I was super lazy to do it on the elegant way, so I just did it the lazy way.
Here is the most ugly function that works:

```
char* foo (char* str)
{
    static char* p;
    int subcontainer = 0;
    int escBackslash = 0;
    int i = 0;
    if(p == NULL)
    {
        p = str;
        if(*p == '\\')
            escBackslash = 1;
    }
    char* offset = NULL;
    for(offset = p; *p != '\0'; p++)
    {
        if(*p == '\\')
        {
            escBackslash = 1;
            i = 1;
            continue;
        }
        if(*p == '"' && escBackslash == 0)
        {
            if(subcontainer < 1)
            {
                subcontainer = 1;
                offset++;
            } else subcontainer = -1;
        }
        if(isspace(*p) && subcontainer < 1)
        {
            if(i) *(p - 3) = '"';
            if(i) *(p - 2) = '\0';
            *(p-(-subcontainer)) = '\0';
            p++;
            return offset + i;
        }
        if(*(p+1) == '\0')
        {
            if(i) *(p - 2) = '"';
            if(i) *(p - 1) = '\0';
            if(subcontainer == -1) *p = '\0';
            p++;
            return offset + i;
        }
        escBackslash = 0;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

---

Testing..

```
int main()
{
    char* str = strdup("\"\\\"test\\\"\" + \"Command 2\" \"Command2\" function \"\\\"nice\\\"\"");

    printf("[%s]\n", str);

    char* str1 = foo(str);

    while(str1 != NULL)
    {
        printf("str[%s]\n", str1);

        str1 = foo(NULL);
    }

    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]